# What is procedure to Host an App in Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Can someone tell me the procedure to host an app in Android Market? I know that there is no review process. But is there any other steps I need to follow to publish my App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need developer account on Android Market (cost 25$), then you need to prepare your application (delete debugging information), sign it with your private release key, align and you may upload it on Market.

For details read Dev Guide: [this article](http://d.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) and all others in "Publishing"

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the docs: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)